# How to get the complete string value while searching a partial string in a file through python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a file which contains the below logs. Now I want to find out where my `TD_Map` string is. I can achieve that through `str.find()` method. But is there a way to get the complete string as a return value? Like for this example I must get `TD_Map2`.
I have to search `TD_Map` string only because the rest part can be any integer constant.

```
Running  
OK, start the cluster assignment.  
: 6035
Warning: The Default Cluster size results in a cluster with multiple Amps on the same Clique.  
The cluster assignment is complete.  
Reading  
da 6-7
Running    
OK.  
The AMPs 6 to 7 are deleted.>  
Reading  
ec   
Running  
OK.  
The session terminated. TD_Map2 is saved.>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways to do this, but it seems like a nice use case for regex:

```
import re

s = """Running  
OK, start the cluster assignment.  
: 6035
Warning: The Default Cluster size results in a cluster with multiple Amps on the same Clique.  
The cluster assignment is complete.  
Reading  
da 6-7
Running    
OK.  
The AMPs 6 to 7 are deleted.>  
Reading  
ec   
Running  
OK.  
The session terminated. TD_Map22 is saved.>
"""

match = re.search('TD_Map([\d]+)', s)
print(match.group(0))  # Print whole "TD_Map2"
print(match.group(1))  # Print only the number "2"
```

Output:

```
TD_Map2
2
```

Comment: @BiswajitMaharana I added a way to get only the number after `TD_Map`, if you prefer it that way.

Comment: Yes both the answers are useful to me. Thanks a ton.

Comment: suppose the string TD_Mapx is present in two different types of strings,   

ex:  
The session terminated. TD_Map22 is saved.>    
TD_Map20 is the gloobal map.  

In this case I want to find the TD_Mapx with in "The session terminated. TD_MapX is saved." string  

Means I want TD_Map22 not TD_Map20

Comment: @BiswajitMaharana You would do: `re.search('(TD_Map([\d]+)) is saved.', s)` and now you can use `group(0)` for the whole `TD_MapXX is saved.`, or `group(1)` for `TD_MapXX`, or `group(2)` for `XX`

Comment: Yes understood. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help :)